# React native component calling firebase function

Tags: firebase, react-native

Im calling a function (signUpUser) from a separate file as follows:

```
   <MyButton
            onPress={() =>
              signUpUser(
                this.state.userName,
                this.state.email,
                this.state.password,
              )
            }
          >
```

in my separate file called firebase.js, the function is as follows:

```
export const signUpUser = (userName, email, password) => {
  Firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      Firebase.database()
        .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          .....etc
        });
    })
    .catch(err => Alert.alert(err));
};
```

Im importing as follows:

```
import signUpUser from '../firebase';
```

Why an i getting an error ""(0, _firebase3.default) is not a function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting a named function. Change import statement to

```
import {signUpUser} from '../firebase';
```

Or if you want you can change the export statement to a default export

```
  const signUpUser = (userName, email, password) => {
  Firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      Firebase.database()
        .ref('profiles/users/' + user.user.uid)
        .set({
          .....etc
        });
    })
    .catch(err => Alert.alert(err));
}; 

export default signUpUser;
```

Comment: Yes that worked - error message makes sense as signUpUser was not recognized as a function.....Im interested though why esLint doesnt pick up on things like this?

Comment: Thats because both versions are correct. In your .js file you can export one default function and as many named functions as you like. in this statement "import React, { Component } from 'react'". React is defined as the default export in react and Component is on of many named exports.

Comment: Oh I see....its looking for an export default in firebase.js....but there isnt one.   thanks